# Counting number of element in collection using HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

Suppose we have a class (Staff) with a Set.
How can we determine the number of elements in the set, using HQL?

Answer (score 2):

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
    "select count(*) from Stuff s inner join s.set countSet  where s.id=:someId");
query.setString("someId", 123);
Long count = (Long)query.uniqueResult();
```

Something like this. If you post your class HQL could be corrected to reflect your names

Comment: Alternatively, could I do "select count(elements(staff.set))..."?

Comment: I don't actually have it in front of me at the moment, so I'm just writing the queries in Notepad. Nevertheless, does my alternative seem correct to you? :)